# XAxis tick interval doesn't change automatically in highcharts gantt

Tags: highcharts

I've implemented a Gantt chart that contains some Gantt long bars and their time period is usually more than a couple of months, moreover, the xAxis of the chart shows years and months as you can see below gif. XAxis's tick-interval should change automatically when I change the range of the Gantt period, but it doesn't!

The desired way is that if I change the time range to a month or smaller, xAxis's tick-interval should change to month/week or month/day.

```
xAxis: {
      maxPadding: 0,
      max: Date.UTC(2024, 07, 16),
      plotLines: [
       // some lines
      ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ticks on the `xAxis` are calculated based on the provided data.
When your data range is wide, the ticks also tend to cover a wider period of time. To change default behaviour you might set the `tickInterval` inside the `afterSetExtremes` function with the use of the `update` method.
Inside you might specify some conditions like for example visible range.

```js
    events: {
      afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
        if (this.chart.xAxis[1].max - this.chart.xAxis[1].min < 36e8) {
          this.update({
            tickInterval: 36e7
          })
        } else {
          this.update({
            tickInterval: undefined
          })
          this.chart.xAxis[1].update({
            tickInterval: undefined
          })
        }
      }
    }
```

**API:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update
**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9poc65fn/

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean on '36e7' and '36e8'? I cannot recognize them! How about months/days?

Comment: It is a number of milliseconds it is 36e7 = 36*10^7.
What do you mean by 'months/days'? How would you like to change them?

Comment: It set xAxis tick-interval to month and week, what number of milliseconds is appropriate for showing month and day on the xAxis?

Comment: You just have to manipulate the tickIntervals. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j0g7u5by/